# how can I make a bit flip function more manegable to return full content?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I am trying to do make a more manageable function without calling each time this long line `data_stream = bytes(b ^ flipmask(0.08) for b in bytearray(content))` I am wokring under python 3 using bit flip algorithm in order to mutate bits , but I want to improve it a little bit to make more managable to call like `flipmask(data)` . I tried to inside that line after functools , but it doesn't work at all

```
def flipmask(p):
    return functools.reduce(lambda a, b: (a << 1) | int(random.random() < p), [0]*8)
```

```
data_stream = bytes(b ^ flipmask(0.08) for b in bytearray(content))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write it like this:

```
def flipMask(p): 
    def apply(b): return b ^ sum( (random.random()<p)<<i for i in range(8) ) 
    return apply
```

then data_stream could be masked using map():

```
data_stream = bytes( map(flipMask(0.8),bytearray(content)) )
```

And, if you're creating byte arrays often:

```
def randomMask(p,content):
    return bytes( map(flipMask(p),bytearray(content)) )
```

and then:

```
data_stream = randomMask(0.8,content)
```